# Reshape long to wide using columns names

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, reshape

Hi I am having trouble reshaping my df.

I have:

```
Netflix     TV      DVD 
   0.1      0.2     0.3
   0.12     0.5     0.15
   0.4      0.6     0.8
            0.5     0.41
            0.41
            0.2
```

And I want to convert my df to look like:

```
Netflix  [0.1, 0.12, 0.4]
TV       [0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.41, 0.2] 
DVD      [0.3, 0.15, 0.8, 0.41]
```

Not sure how *stack()* or *pivot()* would work on a df of this kind. Any help appreciated.

Comment: df.transpose() ?

Comment: So you are trying to turn each column into lists?

Comment: How can your pandas df have columns with different size ? Are the missing values in Netflix and DVD NaNs or None ?

Comment: @OlivierG yes they were NaNs, I wanted to create a list without these NaN values.

Comment: In this case, no. only have 24 columns with ~100 rows of data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### `stack`

Stacking drops null values while reshaping the array

```
df.stack().groupby(level=1).agg(list)

DVD                 [0.3, 0.15, 0.8, 0.41]
Netflix                   [0.1, 0.12, 0.4]
TV         [0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.41, 0.2]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 7):

Remove missing values by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and convert to Series in dictionary comprehension:

```
s = pd.Series({x: df[x].dropna().tolist() for x in df.columns})
print (s)
Netflix                   [0.1, 0.12, 0.4]
TV         [0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.41, 0.2]
DVD                 [0.3, 0.15, 0.8, 0.41]
dtype: object
```

...or in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
s = df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist())
print (s)

Netflix                   [0.1, 0.12, 0.4]
TV         [0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.41, 0.2]
DVD                 [0.3, 0.15, 0.8, 0.41]
dtype: object
```

Last if need 2 columns `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = s.rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')
print (df1)
         a                                b
0  Netflix                 [0.1, 0.12, 0.4]
1       TV  [0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.41, 0.2]
2      DVD           [0.3, 0.15, 0.8, 0.41]
```

Comment: Your comprehension answer in golf form `pd.Series({k: [*df[k].dropna()] for k in df})`

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
> df.T.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist(), axis=1)

Netflix    [0.1, 0.12, 0.4, 0.5, 0.41, 0.2]
TV                    [0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.41]
DVD                        [0.3, 0.15, 0.8]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `groupby` with `columns`

```
df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).apply(lambda x : x.dropna().iloc[:,0].tolist())
Out[20]: 
DVD                 [0.3, 0.15, 0.8, 0.41]
Netflix                   [0.1, 0.12, 0.4]
TV         [0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.41, 0.2]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

If missing values in each columns are NaNs, you can go with this :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Netflix":  [0.1, 0.12, 0.4, None, None, None],
    "TV":       [0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.41, 0.2],
    "DVD":      [0.3, 0.15, 0.8, 0.41, None, None]
}
)
print(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.columns, columns=["Type"])
df2["List_for_Type"] = [
    list(df1[f].dropna())
    for f in df1.columns
]
print(df2)
```

The corresponding output is :

```
  Netflix    TV   DVD
0     0.10  0.20  0.30
1     0.12  0.50  0.15
2     0.40  0.60  0.80
3      NaN  0.50  0.41
4      NaN  0.41   NaN
5      NaN  0.20   NaN

      Type                    List_for_Type
0  Netflix                 [0.1, 0.12, 0.4]
1       TV  [0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.41, 0.2]
2      DVD           [0.3, 0.15, 0.8, 0.41]
```

Hope this helps.